error while loading shared libraries: Question mark
I installed an archived version of CygWin, but when I try to open any of several programs, I get the following error:
D:/bin/(name of program).exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Under normal circumstances, it would name a library that it cannot open, and I would investigate to see where the problem is coming in.  However, in this case, the library is listed simply as a question mark.
I tried to investigate by using gdb; however, it too throws the same error.  How else can I find the cause of this?  Any way to trace system calls?

I suggest to [edit] the question and add the exact version number you installed and a link to the download source. Do you have different versions installed? Or other similar software like MSys2?

This problem is not version-specific.  The real issue is that dependencies don't auto-populate when installing from a hard drive (as opposed to from the internet); so I am missing some dependency, but I don't know how to find which.

Please, add the clarification to the question. Add details from where you got the archived version or how exactly you created it, and how you installed it. This might allow us to try and reproduce your problem.

Just had the same issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78902130/cygwin-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file/78902131#78902131
Use cygcheck:

$ cygcheck  /usr/bin/cmake.exe
:
cygcheck: track_down: could not find cyglzo2-2.dll
:

https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=cyglzo2 says cyglzo2-2.dll is in liblzo2_2 so:
apt-cyg install liblzo2_2


cygcheck: could not find 'D:bingdb.exe'  But this file does not show up on cygwin.com...

It seems you are using CMD and not Cygwin Terminal/Bash . D:bingdb.exe is what come out from D:\bin\gdb.exe after the escape character is swalloed
